# Eclipse TFS Error when double-clicking file - org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open external editor

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am getting the following error when clicking on a .xlsm file in TFS Explorer in Eclipse:

`org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open external editor Excel`

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows:

Navigate to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`.

If `*.xlsm` isn't in the list of File types, then click `Add...` and add it first.

Once this is done, select `*.xlsm` in the top box. I found that "Excel (default)" was the Associated Editor, which was the one that was failing. To get the Excel document to open in Excel instead, I first `Remove`d the broken default editor, and then clicked `Add...`and selected `Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet` from the list.

Note that the list provided depends on the settings on your machine; and it's the file associations list rather than a list of programs. You can also click the "Browse..." button to select a specific program on your machine.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I can't yet - 6 more hours until I can accept my own answer as the correct one